# using excel macro to sum data of specific column and transfer data to sheet2

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm working on Excel 2007 macros where I have to select data in first column from range 0 to 300 , 300 to 600, 600 to 900 and so on incrementing 300.
Where the values of column H with respect to 0 to 300 should be sum and transfer to sheet2 and sum of values of 300 to 600 of H column transferred to sheet2 for all such cases.

I wish to create a button in Excel macro by pressing it transfer all data summing to sheet2. The picture below describes better about my case.

[image: Picture of my problem case]

Comment: (1) Why don't you use formulas? There is no need for VBA I think. Formulas are Excel's strength this is what it was designed for. (2) If you really need VBA then please show the code you already have and ask a *specific* question to it, because this is not a free code writing service. (3) Also try to describe it more detailed, your question is not very clear/exactly. You even didn't ask a question.

Comment: thank you for replying formula is enough for me but i have to add only specific columns for each cases how to do in excel formula and transfer to next sheet

Comment: Sorry but your question is very unclear. You need to be much more specific to get a useful answer. And you need to show what you already have, because we will not do all the work for you. People are here to help you to solve your issues on your own.

Comment: column h2 to h8 and h9 to h10 and h11 to h13 should be automatically selected and sum is it possible to do for such case and transfer to sheet 2

Comment: Then use formulas `=SUM(Sheet1!H2:H8)` and `=SUM(Sheet1!H9:H10)` and `=SUM(Sheet1!H11:H13)` in sheet 2

Comment: this is very direct formula which i need is sum of sheet H2 to H8 may wary from case to case for example some excel sheet if the first column value range 0 to 300 lies in H2 to H15 then h2 to h8 has to be sum. the sheet should automatically select value range in 300 + of column 1 and sum it. i tried with direct formula earlier as given by you it is tedious because i have thousands of data which cannot be done manually.

Comment: This can still be done without VBA (see my answer below). As I said try to use formulas first this is Excel's strength.

Comment: thank you it was usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the formula [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!H:H,Sheet1!A:A,">=0",Sheet1!A:A,"<300")
```

This formula calculates the sum of column H,
where the value in column A is between 0 and 299 (`>=0 and <300`)

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!H:H,Sheet1!A:A,">=300",Sheet1!A:A,"<600")
```

This formula calculates the sum of column H,
where the value in column A is between 300 and 599  (`>=300 and <600`)

> Note: Make sure you use the correct criteria and that eg 300 is not included in both ranges (No overlapping). First range goes from 0 to 299 second range goes from 300 to 599!
>   Therefore I used `>=` and `<`. Make sure that `=` is only used in the upper OR the lower of these both criteria.